# preg_replace with URL problem

Tags: php, regex, url, replace, preg-replace

I use a preg_replace to auto insert HTML links within paragraphs.

Here's what I currently use:

```
$pattern = "~(?!(?:[^<\[]+[>\]]|[^>\]]+<\/a>))(".preg_quote($find_keyword, '/').")\b~msUi";
$replacement = "<a href=\"http://$kw_url\" title=\"$find_keyword\">\$0</a>"; 
$article_content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, stripslashes($article_content), 1, $added );
```

It works great, except 1 problem:

It doesn't match and replace if the keyword is a URL.

If: `$find_keyword="http://www.mysite.com/"` it won't come up with any matches even though it's in the content.

**I already tried escaping $find_keyword with preg_quote, which didn't make any different.**

Any regex experts know a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I already tried escaping forward slashes, which didn't make any different.

Comment: What happens if you pass $find_keyword through preg_quote() (as you should with all input to regex)?

Comment: Have you thought about users that link to `http://example.com/"<script>alert("xss")</script>` ?

Comment: No change when I try: `$pattern = "~(?!(?:[^<\[]+[>\]]|[^>\]]+<\/a>))(".preg_quote($find_keyword).")\b~msUi";`

Comment: @user, all HTML tags are stripped from the original content.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slashes in  your $find_keywords are not escaped which is breaking the pattern.

Comment: Read the comments. They were escaped and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your find_keyword through

```
$find_keyword=preg_quote("http://www.mysite.com/", '/');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: Please post sample $article_content input and your desired output.